# Angular equation for Schrödinger's equation in 3D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation, superposition

In Griffith's book, section 4.1.2,
the angular equation for Schrödinger equation in 3D is expressed as $$\sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin \theta \frac{\partial Y}{\partial\theta})+\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial \phi^2}=-\ell(\ell+1)\sin^2\theta Y.$$
Using the separable solutions $Y(\theta,\phi)=T(\theta)P(\phi)$, he eventually arrived at $$\frac{1}{P(\phi)}\frac{\partial^2 P(\phi)}{\partial \phi^2}=-m^2$$ $$\frac{\partial^2 P(\phi)}{\partial \phi^2}=-m^2P(\phi)$$
where $m$ is a constant.

He then went on to say that the solution for $P(\phi)$ is $$P(\phi)=Ae^{im\phi}$$ instead of the usual $$P(\phi)=Ae^{im\phi}+Be^{-im\phi}$$
by saying that he allows $m$ to be negative.

How are the above two solutions equivalent? For a particular value of $m$, his solution to $P(\phi)$ will always be lacking an extra term $Be^{-im\phi}$, no matter whether $m$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He’s going to take a superposition of such solutions at a later step and sum over all values of $m$. That will pick up the parts of the general solution that you’ve identified.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks.