# Schrödinger's equation for hydrogen atom (azimuthal part)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

Now, The azimuthal part of the Schrödinger's equation for a hydrogen atom (after separating variables) is:
$$ \frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \phi^2} + m^2 \Phi = 0$$
Which has solution $A e^{im\phi} + B e^{-im\phi}$, but I often see people assuming $B=0$, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question has already been answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/514109/angular-equation-for-schr%C3%B6dingers-equation-in-3d), but I will attempt to go through the superposition in more detail.

Firstly, note that for $m = 0$, $\Phi(\phi) = C \phi + D$, but we set $C = 0$ to ensure the wavefunction is single-valued (i.e. to ensure $\Phi(0) = \Phi(2 \pi z)$ for $z \in \mathbb{N}$). This factor of D will just be absorbed into the superposition coefficients for $m = 0$.

Secondly, note that the $\Theta(\theta)$ part of the solution makes use of the associated Legendre polynomials, which are insensitive to the sign of $m$ since the associated Legendre equations depend on $m^2$. Therefore, $\Theta_{m,l}(\theta) = \Theta_{-m,l}(\theta)$.

The general angular solution can be written as:

$$y_l (\phi, \theta) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} \left(A_m e^{i m \phi} + B_m e^{- i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{m,l}(\theta)$$

Rewriting the general solution,

$$\begin{align}
y_l (\phi, \theta) &=  \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \left(A_m e^{i m \phi} + B_m e^{- i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + \sum_{m = -\infty}^{1} \left(A_m e^{i m \phi} + B_m e^{- i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + (A_0 + B_0) \Theta_{0,l}(\theta) \\ &= \sum_{m = -\infty}^{1} \left(A_m e^{i m \phi} + B_m e^{- i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + \sum_{m' = 1}^{\infty} \left(A_{-m'} e^{-i m' \phi} + B_{-m'} e^{ i m' \phi} \right) \Theta_{-m',l}(\theta) + (A_0 + B_0) \Theta_{0,l}(\theta) \\ &= \sum_{m = -\infty}^{1} \left(A_m e^{i m \phi} + B_m e^{- i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \left(A_{-m} e^{-i m \phi} + B_{-m} e^{ i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{-m,l}(\theta) + (A_0 + B_0) \Theta_{0,l}(\theta) \tag{A}\\ &= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \left((A_m + B_{-m}) e^{i m \phi} + (B_m + A_{-m}) e^{- i m \phi} \right) \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + (A_0 + B_0) \Theta_{0,l}(\theta) \tag{B}
\end{align}$$

Define $C_m = A_m + B_{-m}$ so that:

$$\begin{align}
y_l (\phi, \theta) &= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} C_m e^{im\phi} \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} C_{-m} e^{-im\phi} \Theta_{m,l}(\theta) + (A_0 + B_0) \Theta_{0,l}(\theta) \\ &= \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} C_m e^{im\phi} \Theta_{m,l}(\theta)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, it is sufficient to consider $C_m e^{im\phi} \Theta_{m,l}(\theta)$ as the separable solutions for the angular part of the TISE for the hydrogen atom (i.e. the simultaneous eigenstates of $L^2$ and $L_z$).

**Edit: Further Comment**

In this analysis, we started with $B_m \neq 0$, but showed we can regroup the coefficients in the sum to effectively end up with the new coefficients $A'_m = C_m$ and $B'_m = 0$. This means that for all practical purposes, we could have just treated $B_m  = 0$ to begin with.

The confusion arises when one consider just one separable solution in isolation - but we're summing over all of them, so we're allowed to rewrite the summands in different ways if it still leaves the overall sum invariant.

---

- In step (A), I relabelled $m'$ to $m$ since these are just dummy indices.
- In step (B), I made use of $\Theta_{m,l}(\theta) = \Theta_{-m,l}(\theta)$

Comment: Ok, now THIS makes sense, thanks. Also, is it correct to say that we can assume B=0 because everything that's doing is adding an offset, but the choice of axis and where $\phi = 0$ is arbitrary?

Comment: @Dah_Fisicist No problem, I have edited my post to address your question.